# Scalablilty issues with Google Storage upload (from GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, scalability

My application connects to G Suite domains and one rare feature allows for downloading a csv listing all users.

The file is saved to Google Storage and downloaded from there.

While it worked fine for normal domains, a bigger domain (½M users) had scalability-issues. The CSV become huge which leads to:

```
Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 340 MB after servicing 9 requests total
```

To my knowledge I can't do incremental uploads and every workaround I can think of must keep the file in memory at some point.

Any workaround I don't know of?

Out-of-box thinking like incremental save to Drive? Rather avoid the additional scope.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840101/google-app-engine-and-google-sheets-exceeding-soft-memory-limit

Answer (score 0):

If you maintain the requirement of being able to keep the entire file (and/or its associated data) in memory then the only solution is using [a GAE instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) with more memory, via the `instance_class` config item in the [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) config file.

Of course, this solution can only work as long as the memory requirement remains below the free memory of one of the available instance classes, it doesn't scale indefinitely with the CSV size.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented bulk export functionality like this on App Engine before. I did so by using App Engine to launch a *temporary* Compute Engine VM via the API. Once the Compute VM has launched it runs a simple script and then shuts itself down.

The advantage of the compute engine VM is that you can freely write to *temporary* disk space, saving memory. By default GCE instances have 10GB root disk, which is hopefully enough [but this can be increased](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#repartitionrootpd).

In the GCE instance you can make your GSuite API calls and build your export as a temporary file on disk and then when it is ready you can upload it using the [drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-uploads) or google cloud storage apis. Then get the compute engine instance to [shut itself down](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance#stopping_an_instance_through_the_operating_system).

Using the GCE API from App Engine is not as hard as it sounds. I [wrote up a detailed blog post](http://www.zenlambda.com/blog/cost-efficient-scheduled-batch-tasks-google-cloud/) that describes how to setup a webservice on App Engine that can control compute engine instances. At the end it links to a complete deployable example on [github](https://github.com/zenlambda/gae-compute-launcher). You have to write the script to do your export, but if you can make a Docker image of your script, this service can run it!